# UNIX sequential execution of files

Tags: unix

I want to sequentially execute all .sqls in a directory in unix .

Suppose the directory name is /export/home/me
when i list the files in the directory using     ls
it shows

```
a.sql
b.sql
c.sql
```

Now , i need to write a shell script which would go to the directory and loop through all the .sqls in the directory and execute them sequentially .Please suggest

Comment: What do you mean by sequentially? Does the order of execution matter? How do you determine this order?

Comment: i will create separate folders in the directory in the order i want to execute the .sqls.suppose in teh directiry /export/home /me.. i create three sub dirs ddl dml validation.Now each of these subfolders will contain n number of .sqls.hence , i need to loop through all the sub dire3ctories in the mentioned directory and then execute all the .sqls.Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by sequential, you mean sorted alphabetically, then do this,

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `ls folder/*.sql | sort ` # I think the shell lists file sorted alphabetically by default
do
    mysql -u user_name -ppassword database_name < i
done
```

But, too often when you are executing a list of sql files, then you need think of the order, for example, if your design is,Employees and Departments, then if your first sql file creates the Employees table and your second sql file creates the FOREIGN KEY to Departments table, even before executing the third sql file which creates the Departments table, then you will run into trouble.

**Its best to have all the Create/Insert statments of the Database Objects/data in one SQL file in the right order.**

Comment: Thanks....however what you said is critical .Hence suppose i create separate folders in the directory for suppose as for ddls and dmls etcs .how to i then sequntially execute all .sqls in each folder sequentially.Please suggest.and again thanks for your previous suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Assuming order does not matter :

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in folder/*.sql
do
    cat $file #or whatever you want to do with your sql file
done
```